# Rotating an object around the origin

Tags: qt, model, rotation, qml, qt3d

With NumberAnimation, I can rotate a 3d object around one of its x, y, or Z axes. I need to rotate the object around the origin - in the picture it is Z.
[image: wanted situation]

It's a minimal reproducible example

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick3D 1.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    id: window
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    visible: true
    property int i: 0
    property double distance: 1000

    Node {
        id: standAloneScene
        //! [parentnode]

        DirectionalLight {
            ambientColor: Qt.rgba(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        }

        ParallelAnimation{
            id: rotation_y
            running: false
            NumberAnimation { target: cube; property: "eulerRotation.y"; to: 180*i;
                duration: 500; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad}
        }

        Model {
            id: cube
            source: "#Cube"
            y: 18
            scale: Qt.vector3d(1, 1, 1)
            materials: [
                DefaultMaterial {
                    diffuseColor: Qt.rgba(0.228, 0.185, 0.142, 0.5)
                }
            ]
        }

        OrthographicCamera {
            id: cameraPerspectiveIsometry
            position: Qt.vector3d(distance, distance*1.5, distance)
            eulerRotation.x: -45
            eulerRotation.y: 45
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: isometry
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "#848895"
        border.color: "black"

        Label {
            text: "Isometry"
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.margins: 10
            color: "#222840"
            font.pointSize: 14
        }

        View3D {
            id: topLeftView
            anchors.fill: parent
            importScene: standAloneScene
            camera: cameraPerspectiveIsometry

        }
    }


    Button {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.right: right.right
        text: "Start"
        font.pixelSize: height / 2
        onClicked:{
            i++;
            rotation_y.restart();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve] so we can test.

Comment: And please also update the question to include the image URL

Comment: You're not using Qt3D but Qt Quick's 3D capabilities. That's a difference. My suggestion in Qt3D would have been to have a parent object with the global transformation and attach another transformation to the object directly. This allows you to rotate the object around its own coordinate system.